# HTML Date Input to SQL using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

## I have been trying to Use a form written in HTML to input a "Name" and a "Date" into a SQL Database.

Concerning the connection to SQL everything is fine. It is just that using the the HTML5 Date Input type (which include a drop down calendar) the data and PHP does not seem to show up.
When I input the data into the SQL table the "Name" shows up but the "Date" remains blank.
I have put some of my code below. The Form is input.html and the data handling code is table.php. The DB name is users and the table name is staff.

**input.html**

```
<html>
<form action='table.php' method='POST'>
    Name <input type="text" name="name"> <br />
    Date of Expiry <input type="date" name="date1"> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> <br />
</form>
</html>
```

**table.php**

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $date1 = $_POST["date1"];
  $servername = "exampleserver.net";
  $uname = "exampleusername";
  $pass = "password";
  $dbname = "users";
  $errors = array();
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $uname, $pass, $dbname);
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 
  if(mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO staff (`name`, `date1`) VALUES('$name','$date1')")) { 
    header("Location: http://newpageafterdataentry.com"); 
    die(); 
  } else { 
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn); 
  } 
  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Is the datatype of the `date` column 'date'? That would result in the database not accepting any date information not formatted in MySQL date format (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: try dumping `$date1` and post the dump here (`var_dump($date1)`), I suspect that the date format is not as expected

Comment: not directly related to your problem, but please remeber to properly [escape the user input](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) you use in your query!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [strtotime()](http://ca.php.net/strtotime) for converting into timestamp and [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for formatting before saving into DB mysql.Try following:

```
$day1 = strtotime($_POST["date1"]);
$day1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $day1); //now you can save in DB
```

Full code should be:

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $day1 = strtotime($_POST["date1"]);
  $day1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $day1); //now you can save in DB
  $servername = "exampleserver.net";
  $uname = "exampleusername";
  $pass = "password";
  $dbname = "users";
  $errors = array();
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $uname, $pass, $dbname);
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 
  if(mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO staff (`name`, `date1`) VALUES('$name','$date1')")) { 
    header("Location: http://newpageafterdataentry.com"); 
    die(); 
  } else { 
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn); 
  } 
  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Great it worked! Thank you very much Im new to SQL and I wasnt sure about how dates are stored!